# unexpected type(position :text--uuid:dcd5cdf3..@3:13 in java.io.StreamReader@a0190eaa)

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

i am new in blackberry & calling WCF services by using ksoap method.
 when i am calling a service it gives an error message on simulator.
The error is:

> unexpected type(position :text--uuid:dcd5cdf3..@3:13 in java.io.StreamReader@a0190eaa)

this service successfully call in dot net.

My code:

```
        String serviceUrl = "<service url>"; 
        String serviceNameSpace ="<service namespaces>";
        String soapAction = "<service soapaction>";
        String methodName = "logOn";

    SoapObject rpc = new SoapObject(serviceNameSpace, methodName);
    //String a="52";
    //String b="28";

    rpc.addProperty("username", String.valueOf(edUserName.getText()));
    rpc.addProperty("password",String.valueOf(edPaswd.getText()));
   // rpc.addProperty("a","nil");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new  SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.bodyOut = rpc;
    envelope.dotNet = true;          //IF you are accessing .net based web service  this should be true
    envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
    //HttpTransport  ht = new HttpTransport(serviceUrl);
    HttpTransport ht = new HttpTransport(serviceUrl + "; deviceside=true; apn=blackberry.net");


    ht.debug = true;
    //SoapObject result=null;
    //ht.setXmlVersionTag("");

    try
    {
            ht.call(soapAction, envelope);
            String result = (envelope.getResponse()).toString();
            Dialog.alert(result);

            Dialog.alert("login success");
    }
    catch(Exception ex2)
    {
        Dialog.alert("error is :"+ex2.getMessage());
    }


//          if((edUserName.getText().equals("")))
//          {
//              Dialog.alert("Enter User Name ");
//          }
//          if(edPaswd.getText().equals(""))
//          {
//              Dialog.alert("Enter Password");
//              
//          }
```

Answer (score 0):

An error from StreamReader means it has some bad data coming from the HttpTransport. Try doing what is suggested in [this forum post](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/unexpected-type-position-TEXT-Connection-refus/m-p/391596#M75775), especially since it also deals with a .NET WebService.

Comment: plz tell me a actual problem in my code and which changes are required?

Comment: I'm not sure where you need your code to change. The post I linked to pointed out that the only thing affecting the BB code was having the service URL pointing to `http://localhost...` rather than `http://hostname...`. Everything else was to check that your webservice is working right.

Comment: Further down in that forum, it appears that the library being used can't parse HTTP Error messages. It looks like you're code can't parse this string with "uuid:dcd5cdf3...". Are you sure your webservice is sending back valid SOAP/XML?

Comment: i have changed my URL from local host to host name but it gives the same error. Any other changes required in the program?

Comment: i am sure that my webservice is sending back valid data because i have successfully call this webservice from the .net. and i am sending same data to the webservice. where the problem is occure? i have used ksoap2-j2me-core-prev-2.1.2.jar file. is it correct ? if wrong give me a correct lib file. thanks in advance!!!!!!!!

Comment: i have used the below namespace                                                          serviceNameSpace ="http://www.expense.net/mobile";  but normally we used namespace is http://tempuri.org/     is their issue regarding that?

Comment: i think the issues is in http connection. do you know more about that error? is their any incorrect code in the program. anybody knows about this please help me?